# Determine a stable and a center manifold for the rest point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Recently, I dealt with determining stable/ unstable/ center manifold. Here is one task.

> > Determine a stable and a center manifold at the rest point of the system
> >     $$
> > \dot{x}=x^2,\qquad\dot{y}=-y.
> > $$

I think this is not that difficult here. The linearization matrix is 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
$$
so the eigenvalues are
 $\lambda_1=0,\lambda_2=-1$.

I think a center manifold is given by
$$
W^c: y=h(x)\text{ with }h(0)=h'(0)=0\text{ and } \dot{y}=h'(x)\dot{x}
$$
So, formally, one can make the start $h(x)=ax^2+bx^3+...$ and determine the coeffcients. Here, I simply get $h(x)\equiv 0$ so that the center manifold is simply
$$
W^c: y=0
$$
Similarly, I get for the stable manifold that
$$
W^s: x=g(y)=0.
$$

Am I right?

I know that the stable manifold is unique but the center manifold is not. What would be another center manifold?

Comment: I ask for verifying my results since these things are new to me.

Comment: So you keep asking the same thing. Why do you think that "the center manifold is not [unique]"?

Comment: @Jonas Because every book says that center manifold is not unique. In fact, any trajectory that goes to equilibrium from the left can be stitched with right half of $y =0$ or with trajectory that goes to equlibrium from the right side of $Oy$ axis. And that would be another center manifold. However, it's again a basic fact that needs just careful reading of relevant chapters in a course book or other few books.

Comment: @Evgeny You really need to study, what you say above shows that you have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @Jonas, sorry, only the first sentence was addressed to you. The latter part was addressed to Rhjg and I forgot to mention this explicitly.

Comment: @Evgeny So indeed you think that the center manifold is never unique... and that this is "a basic fact that needs just careful reading of relevant chapters in a course book or other few books". I rest my case.

Comment: @Jonas I admit that I was inaccurate in this statement. Correct version would be "while global center manifold is unique, local center manifold might be non-unique". If you don't agree with this, take a look at slide 7 [here](http://www.iki.rssi.ru/seminar/virtual/an_part2.pdf).

Comment: Second version needs correction too. All proofs of global center manifold theorem that I know require global Lipschitz continuity and local center manifold depends on what cut is used to make system of interest globally Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Note that in general a global center manifold may also not be unique (taking as definition a smooth invariant manifold tangent to the center space).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is appropriate to note explicitly the following: in some cases the center manifold is unique.

This comment (promoted to answer, since there is nothing more to add) applies both to local center manifolds and global center manifolds, even irrespectively of the space in which we look for the functions of which the manifold is a graph.